# How do I solve this crash from receiving data using urllib?

Tags: ubuntu, urllib

I'm trying to use urllib to get data from http://ustc.edu.cn. However, when I try to assign the return from the `recv` call, the program crashes with this traceback:

```
>>> urllib.urlopen('http://ustc.edu.cn')
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
        return getattr(self, name)(url)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 351, in open_http
        errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1202, in getreply
        response = self._conn.getresponse()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1127, in getresponse
        response.begin()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
        line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
        data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Occasionally, it will also return a "connection reset by peer" message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've made some edits to your question to make it a bit clearer. However, for us to really help you, we'll need to know some more details - you should post the code you're using, as well as just the stack trace. The more detailed you can be, the better, in general.

Comment: Looks like you pressed `Ctrl+C` during the fetch, interrupting the operation.